# How to automatically delete user profile connected in a domain (Windows 7) once log off

Tags: windows, user-profile

How to automatically delete user profile connected in a domain (Windows 7) after logging off?

Answer (score 1):

This is easily done by using mandatory accounts.
Every time you relog, switch user, or reboot the profile will be loaded back to default since the date you set it to mandatory.

See it like a kiosk/internet cafee account, users can log in, use internet and save documents for printing or save it to flash storage.

Here is how you do it:
-Create your user account and manage the settings (start menu, icoons on the desktop etc etc)
-When you are done configuring the account, loggoff so that the user account will be saved on the server (profile path ad)
-Then rename the NTUSER.DAT to NTUSER.MAN this will change it to a mandatory account, every user switch will set the settings back from step one.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg241183(v=ws.10).aspx

No third party software, or group policy's needed. (tho you can adjust the user account by using localGPO's, like start page, taskbar icoons, allow them to right click or not etc)

-Dont use guest accounts, since the users cant instal or change any software during their loggin, so you will get a load on your IT department.

Greetz!

Answer (score 0):

Put the user in the local windows7 guest group.

Edited: 
If a user is added to the Guests group (or the Domain Guests group, which belongs to the Guests group), when the user logs on, that user's profile information is only stored temporarily. When that user logs off, the entire profile is deleted. This includes everything stored in the %userprofile% directory: the user's registry hive information, custom desktop icons, and so on. From [Profiles for Members of Guests Group Are Deleted](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/165398)

Edited:

Use [delprof2](https://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/) if you can't add the user in the group.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but is there any other ways aside from putting his account to guest group.

Comment: @VanessaVicencio Windows will erase the profile at logoff when hes in that group. Do you use roaming profile or such, or it's for public computer ?

Comment: We are not using roaming profile neither public computer.

Comment: @VanessaVicencio See my answer, i updated it, use delprof2, it's a good way too. I used delprof /q (from microsoft) in the past, that new tool is for windows 7+